# My prefix is plant, My suffix is grant

Tags: riddle, rhyme

```
My prefix is plant.

My suffix is grant.

My infix is a piece of cake.

My whole is wealth at stake.
```

Hint:

> Above your waist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> treasure

My prefix is plant.

> trea -- like tree

My suffix is grant.

> sure

My infix is a piece of cake.

> ease

My whole is wealth at stake.

> treasure - like when others find your buried treasure, or when you can't find the hidden treasure

Hint:

> Above your waist. -- your chest is above your waist, suggesting treasure chest.

Comment: i don't understand how the second and third lines work out, i can't think of any phrases that use those words together.

Comment: Hmmm... I think it's quite a liberty with the format to use more than one 'homophone' or misspelled -fix... It's no wonder this one went unsolved. Please note though that only 4 days had passed since you set this riddle - there was no need to reveal the answer so soon. I have seen riddles that have still been unsolved over a year later and then the right person has come along and BOOM it falls at last. Don't feel you need to give the solution after just a few days - give the community time :) Just a tip, meant kindly!

Comment: @Bewilderer [A piece of cake](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/piece%20of%20cake)

Comment: @Stiv Thanks. Still, from what I've seen, using homophones do not seem uncommon.

Comment: @riskymysteries I've seen the *occasional* homophone, but I can't think of a riddle with more than one without it being indicated somewhere that this should be expected... The most common Riley approach is to pick words that can be split into 3 other real words - certainly these seem to have a greater success rate (and possibly satisfaction for the solver too)...